# Flex - Security Sandbox violation - ERROR#2048

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, crossdomain.xml

So if i put -http://xxx.xx.xx.x/website/website.html  and try to use an HTTPService with in the swf to contact -https://yyy.yy.yy.y/resources/script, I get the sandbox error.
If I put  -https://yyy.yy.yy.y/crossdomain.xml  in the browser and access it everything in the crossdomain file looks fine.
wWen i go back and try to use the HTTPService from -http://xxx.xx.xx.x/website/website.html  everything now works until i close the browser which i assume clears the cache.

********crossdomain.xml*********

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<cross-domain-policy>
  <site-control permitted-cross-domain-policies="master-only"/>
  <allow-access-from domain="*"/>
  <allow-http-request-headers-from domain="*" headers="*"/>
</cross-domain-policy>
```

********Action Script*************

```
Security.loadPolicyFile("https://xxx.xx.xx.x/crossdomain.xml");
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Change the following line:

```
<allow-access-from domain="*"/>
```

to:

```
<allow-access-from domain="*" secure="false" />
```

You can read more about it at adobe.com...

http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/142/tn_14213.html

Answer (score 2):

We found that Chrome will refuse self-signed SSL certificates but Firefox and Safari will plow on ahead.  Try a different browser and see if that works for you.