# connect to socket in as3

Tags: actionscript-3, sockets, cross-domain-policy

I want to make a chat app using socket in as3.
I have already followed many examples but none of them helped much.
Right now i am following [this](http://www.kilometer0.com/blog/code/php-xml-socket-server/) link.

I am running php at localhost using xampp.Also i have already ran policySocketServer.php,socketServer.php as written in page comments.

i am using this to load policy file

```
Security.loadPolicyFile("xmlsocket:127.0.0.1/chat/crossdomain.xml:843");
```

and to connecting to `ourXMLSocket.connect("http://127.0.0.1/chat/", "9999");`

but i am getting these errors

```
    IOErrorEvent error  Error #2031: Socket Error. URL: http://127.0.0.1/chat/
security error  Error #2048: Security sandbox violation: file:///C|/Users/irfan/Desktop/socket%5Fserver/socket%5Fserver.php/AS3%20Game%20Implementation/TestGame.swf cannot load data from http://127.0.0.1/chat/:9999.
```

Answer (score 1):

Read the error message:

> Security sandbox violation: file:///C........swf cannot load data
>   from http://....

Try running your swif from the http protocol not file protocol. That should fix the security issues.

Comment: now i embed my swf in html and i am running it by using http://127.0.0.1/chat/index.html but still i am getting security error. Error #2048

Comment: In SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR listener i am getting this
event.text=Error #2048, event.errorID=0,nothing more than this.
Yes but now no IOError is coming.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5157089/flex-security-sandbox-violation-error2048