# How to send binary content to a servlet in Action Script

Tags: java, actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I have an action script function in a file which sends a pdf file as binary content to a servlet as shown below.

```
private function savePDF(pdfBinary:ByteArray, urlString:String):void{

            try{
                Alert.show("in savePDF urlString" +urlString);
                //result comes back as binary, create a new URL request and pass it back to the server
                var header:URLRequestHeader = new URLRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/octet-stream");

                var sendRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest(urlString);
                sendRequest.requestHeaders.push(header);
                sendRequest.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
                sendRequest.data = pdfBinary;

                Alert.show("in savePDF calling sendToURL"); 

                sendToURL(sendRequest);
            }catch(error:*){
                Alert.show("in savePDF err" +error);    
                trace(error);
                }
            }
```

This code works fine in flashplayers versions like 10,11,13

But fails in flashplayers of higher versions like 14.0.0.126 or above.

I get the following error

```
SecurityError: Error #3769: Security sandbox violation: Only simple headers can be used with navigateToUrl() or sendToUrl().
```

Any suggestions on how to resolve this ?

Comment: This is a known issue caused by a security update in a recent version of Flash Player; see https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1521470 and https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=3759971.  @CyanAngel's answer will let you send your request without being blocked by this security check.

Comment: Is there any issue with "passing data to swf file using FlashVars variable" in recent version of Flash Player ? I get all the variables as null

Comment: Not that I know of.  However, it can be tricky to get right if you're not sure how to pass in variables.

Answer (score 2):

You could try using a [`URLLoader`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7cfd.html#WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7cf5) instead of `sendToURL()`

```
Alert.show("in savePDF urlString" +urlString);
var header:URLRequestHeader = new URLRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/octet-stream");

var sendRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest(urlString);
sendRequest.requestHeaders.push(header);
sendRequest.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
sendRequest.data = pdfBinary;

Alert.show("in savePDF calling URLLoader"); 

var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
loader.load(sendRequest);
```

Comment: I get the following error if I use URLLoader Error #2044: Unhandled securityError:. text=Error #2048: Security sandbox violation: <my URL>

Comment: You may need to set up a cross domain policy, see : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5157089/flex-security-sandbox-violation-error2048